# NGINX User Based Website Directories & Regex

Tags: nginx

I want to make use of the **alias function** in NGINX to accomplish something simple. I have searched the internet for the last 3 days and found nothing but bad or outdated examples and was hoping someone could post a working example based on a newer version of NGINX.

I have the following url:

http://mysite.com/**username_123**

My question is how do I make NGINX forward this request to the internal user folder:

html/profiles/**username_123**

...and return its index.php page?

Please keep in mind that this index.php page is passed to the php FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I had the same problem finding useful information about apache style aliasing or script aliasing.  I ended up [blogging about it](http://zaplabs.com/blog/jeff-clark/apache-style-aliasing-nginx) the other day.

This was tested with nginx version 1.0.5, but should work on 0.85 also.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.php;
    root /var/www;
    location ~ ^/username_123(.*)\.php($|/) {
        include php_fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/profiles/username_123$1.php;
    }
    location ~ ^/username_123(.*) {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html/profiles/username_123$1;
    }
}
```